# Converting D3.js CSS Styles to Inline Styles

Tags: jquery, css, svg, d3.js

I have two types of graphs that I am trying to export. I am using SVG Crowbar, and it works great in Chrome, but in Firefox it does not export the CSS with it (And I'm just not going to bother with IE). I have decided to convert all of the CSS to inline styles. However, I am running into 2 problems (1 with each graph).

In the bar graph, I can't seem to apply the, "stroke: black;" to only the axis, and not the axis label. The, "stroke: black" is making the labels blurry, and unattractive. Here is a JSFiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/UK8bw/10/. Here is the code for the axis/labels. I tried to split them up, without success. I left the relevant CSS commented out in the CSS section.

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "xAxis")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.6em")
    .attr("dy", "-0.195em")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "rotate(-90)"
    });  

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "yAxis")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Y-Axis Label");
```

---

I also have a pie graph. I managed to convert all of the CSS styles to inline styles, however I ran into a new problem. The legend and the graph itself are displayed on two different SVGs. Because of this, I cannot download them both to one file. Is there any way to display both the chart and the legend on the same SVG? Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/7/

Comment: The easiest thing to do is probably to set the styles you want changed again, i.e. `.selectAll("text").style("stroke", "none")` etc.

Comment: I managed to figure out the second problem with the pie graph. Here is a JSFiddle with the fix in anyone is interested: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/8/. I'm still looking for an answer to the first question though. If anyone has a fix, please post it!

Comment: @Kotthoff - I tried adding the line `svg.selectAll("text").style("stroke", "none")` at the end, and that did not work. Where would I place that code?

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/UK8bw/11/

Comment: Thank you very much! I would upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I've added it as an answer, feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is probably to set the styles you want explicitly, i.e.

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "xAxis")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .style("stroke", "none")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.6em")
  .attr("dy", "-0.195em")
  .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "rotate(-90)"
  });
```

Updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UK8bw/11/).